# Parsing the JSON formatted string/Array from the service in Blackberry

Tags: json, parsing, blackberry

I am trying to send some data to a server, so once the data is received or any error occurs while the transaction is processing, the server would intimate to its clients through a JSON type of response. when i post a a set value , as i said, its it returns a JSON format like the one below,

```
{"code":0,"err":"Missing 'method'."}. // JSON format returned from the server

  /** Method that is responsible for converting the JSON format to other types*/

  public static void convertFromJSON(String json) throws JSONException {

// the string json holds JSON format string that i mentioned above

   // Creates a JSONArray with the values provided in the string json
   JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(json); // error : The constructor JSONArray(String) refers to the missing type JSONException

    }
```

I need to parse this JSON format and evaluate it depending upon the value that it returns. I have imported the appropriate JSON JAR too.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
        JSONObject row =   new JSONObject(json);

        String code  = row.get("code").toString();
        String err  = row.get("err").toString();
```

Comment: Hi John, i tried your way, but getting the same compilation message that i got. (The constructor JSONObject(String) refers to the missing type JSONException), Please let me know where am i wrong. Whether there is any thing strange happening in jar that i chosed ?

Comment: Hi, there was a problem in the jar file that i have dowwnloaded, i changed the jar file, now it works fine. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public static void convertFromJSON(String json){
  JSONObject entries = JSONValue.parse(json);
}
```

Also, the sample you've provided won't parse into a JSONArray.

Comment: Hi, once i import the jar file, i an getting this error :
Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.
tmp3139/org/json/me/JSONArray.class: Error!: Invalid class file: Incorrect classfile version
Packaging project BBProject failed (took 1.496 seconds)